# <?php echo $title ?> vs <?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?> Wordpress Security

Tags: security, validation, sanitization

Reading this great article **[Data Validation and Sanitization in Wordpress](http://devotepress.com/coding/data-validation-sanitization-wordpress-1/)** I've noticed that in my blog, in header.php, I used `<?php echo $title ?>` in a pair of codes.

According to the above [article](http://devotepress.com/coding/data-validation-sanitization-wordpress-2/), in order to secure data, it is important to validate the data itself for data's without validation are vulnerable to hackers.

As suggested by the author, I changed my initial `<?php echo $title ?>` into `<?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?>`.

This is the code *before* changes:

```
<span class="ads">
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo '<span><a href="/?page_id=175" title="inserisci un annuncio gratis">Pubblica il   tuo annuncio gratis: &egrave; facile e veloce!</a></span>';
} else {
echo '<span><a class="simplemodal-login simplemodal-submit" href=""><?php echo $title ?>Pubblica il tuo annuncio gratis: &egrave; facile e veloce!</a>   </span>';
}
?>
</span>
```

This is the code *after* changes:

```
<span class="ads">
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo '<span><a href="/?page_id=175" title="inserisci un annuncio gratis">Pubblica il   tuo annuncio gratis: &egrave; facile e veloce!</a></span>';
} else {
echo '<span><a class="simplemodal-login simplemodal-submit" href=""><?php echo  esc_html( $title ); ?>Pubblica il tuo annuncio gratis: &egrave; facile e veloce!</a>   </span>';
}
?>
</span>
```

Now my question is (I guess it's a newbie one!): the change I made is good for my blog' security?

---

Comment: This is already save data. Like most stuff that comes from core as post data.

Comment: You have some error in code (echo in echo and php in php) : `else {echo '<span><a class="simplemodal-login simplemodal-submit" href="">' . esc_html( $title ) . '</a>   </span>';}`

Answer (score 3):

In the articles case, `$title` is an arbitrary value, as such it should be escaped via html, but, if it was gotten from a WordPress core function it is probably safe, but you should check anyway

For example, `get_the_title()` can contain html markup and is not escaped by default.

Eitherway post and page titles should not have html in them. Styling is for themes, not for content.

You should validate all data at entry, and that is where you should focus your efforts. What your doing improves your security but by how much depends on where the data is coming from.

I recommend you escape all data on input and output, but do it out of habit rather than for specific exceptional cases

Comment: Thank you Tom, as I understand this is only a minor hack for in this case data comes directly from my database and not from external inputs (as it would be with forms). This issue came up for using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/websitedefender-wordpress-security/ plugin, the security scan report alerted me about this source code disclosure.. Grazie again, diana

Comment: I've ammended my answer

Comment: > Eitherway post and page titles should not have html in them. Styling is for themes, not for content.

---

Then why does the Theme Unit Test import data file explicitly contain a post that can show whether a post title correctly supports styling?

Comment: Because some people DO use html in titles, and so its a legacy thing, you can't just break people's sites with new themes. Even then it gives sub optimal results. If you really must, use wp_kses on the title, otherwise mark up shouldn't be in titles

Answer (score 1):

The post title **can** contain markup, and it will **not** be escaped by WordPress by default. To get an escaped title use:

- [`the_title_rss()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_title_rss) (`print get_the_title_rss()`) or
- [`the_title_attribute()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute)